# iReport : List Standard Size Issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a strange problem with Jasper Reports`iReport:

I have to use Version 3.7.6 and in this version I have to create a dynamic table.

The user is able to define how many columns the table will have and I am calculating this table in the Java - Backend before report initialization and present it to the user. I am not using the table component for this but instead a List of Textfields:

The Java Representation looks like this (very simple):

```
List<List<String>>
```

What I am doing is to take a list component that is using subreports to print the contents of the many strings into the report. The List component is printing columns of text fields next to each other (Print Order Horizontal). The subreport consists of nothing but a textfield. This textfield is printed over and over for every column and in the end I have a nice table.

**This works very well.**

What doesn´t work is when I try to make the text field in the subreport wider.
When it has the standard size of 53px the table looks very well.

When I increase the size I notice that the textfield itself gets wider but the list component still thinks the next column should be 53px. So the text fields overlap each other because the list component refuses to increase its size.

**Is there any way to tell the list component to increase its column size when printing horizontal ?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer:

The size of the columns for the list component is derived from the columnWidth property of the report. When I change this I can create wider textfields ...